# Wrong order of output with bind operations in logger Monad

Tags: haskell, monads

I was doing some exercises to try and get a better understanding of Monads and their bind operation(s) in Haskell. To do so, I decided to write a logger which keeps track of executed operations on the way. Therefore, I created following data type:

```
data Log e a = Error e | Result a String deriving (Show)
```

with as Monad instance:

```
instance Monad (Log e) where
    (>>=) (Error e) _      = Error e
    (>>=) (Result x log) f = case f x of
                                  Error e       -> Error e
                                  Result r log' -> Result r (log ++ log')
    return x               = Result x ""
```

In order to test the logger in a scenario, I wrote a data type which represents simple arithmetic operations. The data type looks like:

```
data Exp = Lit Int | Add Exp Exp | Mul Exp Exp | Div Exp Exp deriving Show
```

Having division present, I want to use the Error constructor of the Log data type to handle division by zero.

The eval function evaluating the expressions and tracing on the way will look like:

```
evalTrace :: Exp -> Log String Int
```

A query of what the end result should look like:

```
Main> evalTrace (Add (Lit 1) (Mul (Lit 2) (Lit 3)))
(7, "Add\nLit\nMul\nLit\nLit\n")
```

Here is what I wrote so far:

```
evalTrace :: Exp -> Log String Int
evalTrace (Lit x)   = Result () "Lit\n" >> return x
evalTrace (Add x y) = do
                        rx <- evalTrace x
                        ry <- evalTrace y
                        Result () "Add\n" >> return (rx + ry)
evalTrace (Mul x y) = do
                        rx <- evalTrace x
                        ry <- evalTrace y
                        Result () "Mul\n" >> return (rx * ry)
evalTrace (Div x y) = do
                        rx <- evalTrace x
                        ry <- evalTrace y
                        if ry == 0
                            then (Error "division by zero")
                            else Result () "Div\n" >> return (div rx ry)
```

The arithmetic is handled correctly, but it seems that the log messages are printed out of order. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here, but I can't seem to get the problem fixed.

Query:

```
Main> evalTrace (Add (Lit 1) (Mul (Lit 2) (Lit 3)))
Result 7 "Lit\nLit\nLit\nMul\nAdd\n"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log messages are actually printed in order, you can see that

```
evalTrace (Add x y) = do
  rx <- evalTrace x
  ry <- evalTrace y
  Result () "Add\n" >> return (rx + ry)
```

desugars into `evalTrace x >>= (\rx -> evalTrace y >>= (\ry -> Result () "Add\n" >> return (rx + ry)))`.
You can obviously see here that the log of `evalTrace x` should come first, then the log of `evalTrace y`, then the actual "Add" log.
You're doing a post-order Tree traversal of your expressions, as is the case with standard arithmetic interpreters.
You're looking for :

```
do
  log "Add\n"
  rx <- evalTrace x
  ry <- evalTrace y
  return (rx + ry)
```

with `log = Result ()`

Note that `do {a;b}` desugars into `a >> b`, so you could've written your original code this way :

```
evalTrace (Add x y) = do
  rx <- evalTrace x
  ry <- evalTrace y
  Result () "Add\n"
  return (rx + ry)
```